# Within how many blocks does a monster have to be close to my bed to trigger the warning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sometimes when I want to sleep within my house, I can't because of the "You may not sleep now, there are monsters nearby" warning. Within how many blocks does a hostile mob have to be to my bed to trigger this warning?

Comment: [You're gonna need a bigger house.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I91DJZKRxs) ;)

Comment: @gnovice Uh - my house is 5 stories high.

Comment: With my house it says the message and there's no monsters so I dig down and find a cave very close about 10 to 20 blocks away Get off my lawn, I need some shut eye mobs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Sleep_interruption

> The system is much simpler since the full release — sleep is not
> allowed within 10 blocks of a hostile mob.

Quoted from the minecraft wiki. Hope this helps.

Comment: 10 blocks horizontally *and* vertically?

Comment: What about diagonals?

Comment: Actually, it is +/- 8 blocks sideways and +/- 5 blocks vertically. That is, a 16x16x10 box centered on the edge of the bed.

Answer (score 2):

If a hostile mob is in the ten block radius you will not be allowed to sleep.

Answer (score -2):

You can build a 4x3 platform 13 blocks above the ground(for safety) and put a bed on it.
I've tried it and I was able to sleep without any prompts.